# UICollectionView specific cell bring front of oder cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As you can see in below video, in collectionView there are 3 cells. I want  it become bigger when I touch in centre. everything is OK except one thing.

As you can see in video when order cell is visible and centre cell is bigger in bring to back of visible cell and make it untouchable.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn4ujvr6t9f9e2c/ScreenRecording_07-14-2018%2013-08-04.MP4?dl=0

Is there any solution that centre cell always be in front of order cell?

Comment: Might I suggest doing the animation in an animated transition to a new viewcontroller. If not setting the layer zIndex to a higher number will solve the problem but you will always have to be changing it so the first suggestion is better.

Comment: @agibson007 can you please more explain about first suggestion?